# HQL Query not able to sort by distinct

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have an HQL query which runs just fine when I do a simple distinct:

```
select distinct type from ACLIENT where showing = 1
```

However now I want to sort the results so I tried this:

```
select distinct type as btype from ACLIENT where showing = 1 order by btype
```

But this does not work and I get an SQLGrammarException.
Can anyone suggest what is the mistake I am making and how to sort the results by distinct type?

The Hibernate version I am using is 3.6 and full stack trace is:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2235)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2129)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2124)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:401)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:363)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1149)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:67)
    ... 126 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "btype" does not exist
  Hint: Perhaps you meant to reference the column "aclient0_.type".
  Position: 204
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2161)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1890)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:560)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:417)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:302)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:353)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1812)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:697)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2232)
```

Comment: You should edit your post and add the complete error message/stacktrace because they (probably) mention which token caused the issue
Also the [hibernate tools for hql](http://hibernate.org/tools/) might be helpful

Comment: it is unable to recognise the alias  for distinct type and stacktrace show:"Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "btype" does not exist
  Hint: Perhaps you meant to reference the column "aclient0_.type".
  Position: 204"

Comment: ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list you are  using alias use type

Comment: Please post the ACLIENT class body

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug with aliases in the order by clause in Hibernate 3.6.as reported here:https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-892
Solution or workaround as per the link is:

```
select distinct type as btype from AirsClient where showing = 1 order by col_0_0_
```

i.e instead of alias I use col_0_0 and it works.

Comment: doesnt this work? `select distinct type as btype from ACLIENT where showing = 1 order by type`